# Scala - Sort a Map based on Tuple Values

Tags: scala, data-structures, scala-collections, scala-2.10, sortedmap

I am attempting to sort a Map based on Value Tuples

```
val data = Map("ip-11-254-25-225:9000"  -> (1, 1413669308124L), 
               "ip-11-232-145-172:9000" -> (0, 1413669141265L), 
               "ip-11-232-132-31:9000"  -> (0, 1413669128111L), 
               "ip-11-253-67-184:9000"  -> (0, 1413669134073L), 
               "ip-11-232-142-77:9000"  -> (0, 1413669139043L))
```

The criteria of sort should be based on both the values in the tuple

I tried

```
SortedMap[String, (Long,Long)]() ++ data
```

but with no success.

Can someone please suggest a better way to sort first on `tuple._1` and then on `tuple._2`

Comment: use `def sortWith(lt: (A, A) ⇒ Boolean): List[A]` and `compareTo` function to compare your tuples.

Comment: And note SortedMap sorts on keys, and not on values so it's not what you want anyway

Comment: You can use a `ListMap` and use `sortBy(_._2)` as mentioned in the accepted answer to [this question].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can select which element in the tuple has priority in the sorting; consider this

```
data.toSeq.sortBy {case (k,(a,b)) => (k,a,b) }
```

In the `case` pattern we extract each element of the (nested) tuples. In the expression above we sort by key, then by first element in value tuple and then second. On the other hand, this

```
data.toSeq.sortBy {case (k,(a,b)) => (k,b) }
```

will sort by key and last element in value tuple, and this

```
data.toSeq.sortBy {case (k,(a,b)) => (a,b) }
```

by the values of the map; this one

```
data.toSeq.sortBy {case (k,(a,b)) => (b) }
```

will sort by the last element in the values tuple.

**Update** As helpfully pointed out by @Paul a `Map` preserves no ordering, hence the result remains here as a sequence.

Comment: A Map has no ordering. So the .toMap throws away the ordering. Try printing the result of the .sortBy, then print the final map - they'll be in different order

Comment: @Paul absolutely, many thanks; please kindly note the update.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
data.toVector.sortBy(_._2)
```

This will sort the entries by the values (the tuples), where the order depends on both tuple arguments.  The default sort behavior for a tuple is to sort on `_1` and then `_2`:

```
Vector((2,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,1)).sorted
// Vector((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sorting Tuples

First note that if you sort a collection of tuples you will get the same result as you expect, i.e. first items will be compared first and then second items.

For example `(a1, b1) > (a2, b2)` if and only if `(a1 > a2) || ((a1 == a2) && (b1 > b2))`.

So for getting the expected result in terms of sorting tuples you don't need to do anything.

Then it remains to how to sort a `map` based on values and how to preserve the order after sorting.

### Sort `map` on *values*

You can use the `sortBy` method of `List` and then use an ordered data structure to preserve the ordering, like this:

```
new scala.collection.immutable.ListMap() ++ data.toList.sortBy(_._2)
```

If you run this in Scala REPL you will get the follwoing result:

```
scala> new scala.collection.immutable.ListMap() ++ data.toList.sortBy(_._2)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,(Int, Long)] = Map(ip-11-232-132-31:9000 -> (0,1413669128111), ip-11-253-67-184:9000 -> (0,1413669134073), ip-11-232-142-77:9000 -> (0,1413669139043), ip-11-232-145-172:9000 -> (0,1413669141265), ip-11-254-25-225:9000 -> (1,1413669308124))
```

If you simply want to sort them and traverse the result (i.e. if you don't need a `map` as result) you don't even need to use `ListMap`.